# Had eTAs and Passports but Still Denied Boarding Without Explanation

Tags: denied-boarding

We planned a trip to Canada (YYC) from Mexico (MEX). We have valid Mexico passports and received our eTAs well in advance. At the airport, we were denied boarding and the only explanation was advice to contact the Canadian embassy. The Canadian embassy contact we have is only for Canadians. While we continue pursuing this avenue, we are wondering if anyone else has figured out how to determine why boarding is denied when we, apparently, have everything in order.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything you will hear from here is conjecture. There are 1001 reasons why a person can be denied boarding.

Comment: Direct flight or layover in the US?

Comment: Just to make this entirely clear: A gate agent refused to let you board the flight and didn't give you any explanation as to why? Not even a hint of what the issue might be?

Comment: @TooTea That is very typical if there is an immigration issue. Gate agents do not have detailed immigration info. Their notifications just say deny boarding without giving details.

Comment: @user56513 OK, I thought so. Still, I'd expect something along the lines of "there's an immigration issue", so that you know it's not the airline's fault.

Comment: @brhans if the denial of boarding had been due to improper documents for a layover in the US, the traveler should have been advised to get in touch with US authorities, not Canadian.  I suppose the same would have been true if the denial had been due to a US no-fly list, but I'm less certain of that.

Comment: Snoopy, have you [checked your eTA status](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/check-status.html)?  Are you certain that you entered your passport numbers correctly?  Canada is very noisy about that, so I presume that many people have put them in incorrectly.  They are quite clear that if you do this, you will be unable to board your flight.  Some very cursory research suggests that a Mexican ordinary passport number should be the letter G followed by eight numeric digits.

Comment: You've given us basically zero information to work from, so we can't possibly answer your question.